# Update a widget in the background from database

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a widget (called **RecordsListWidget**) that load a list of records from a database using **sqflite**.

From this widget (or a third widget) is possible to open another widget (called **NewRecordFormWidget**) with `Navigator.pushNamed(context, NewRecordFormWidget.ROUTE);`

In **NewRecordFormWidget** the user can enter some data, and save a new record in the database.

I would like to display the new record in **RecordsListWidget** after the user left the **NewRecordFormWidget**. What is the best approach?

I'd like to keep using sqflite, and not migrate to another library if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pop back to **RecordsListWidget** from **NewRecordFormWidget**, you can send back a boolean as a check for if the UI is to be updated or not.

For example (loose code) -

```
class ClassOne {
  Button(
    onPressed () async {
      var res = await Navigator.push(ClassTwo);
      if(res)
        //run query on database again and update UI
      else
        //do nothing
    }
  )
}

class ClassTwo {
  Button(
    onPressed () {
      Navigator.pop(context, true);  //send true for updating the UI, or false for not updating
    }
  )   
}
```